# scrape information from multiple urls using a for loop in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape information from multiple urls. I use the following code but it doesn't work. May someone please points me to where I have gone wrong?

```
import scrapy

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    domain = "http://www.amazon.com/dp/"
    ASIN = ['B01LA6171I', 'B00OUKHTLO','B00B7LUVZK']

    def start_request(self):
        for i in ASIN:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=domain+i,callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
       title =response.css("span#productTitle::text").extract_first().strip()
       ASIN_ext = response.xpath("//input[@name='ASIN']/@value").extract_first()
       data = {"ASIN":ASIN_ext,"title":title,}
       yield data
```

Comment: Please explain what error do you get?

Comment: The log didn't show any errors. But just says 0 pages are crawled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add an 's' to the first function

```
def start_requests(self):
```

Subtle difference, but Scrapy looks for that specific function so it has to match perfectly.

Comment: Thanks! It works if i move the 'domain' and 'ASIN' variable into the start_requests() block. I am a newbie to python and scrapy. May I how to make these two variable accessible for all the functions defined in the class?

Comment: In your case, just prefix them with the class name when you reference them. The way you defined them is fine, but when you go to reference it would be spider1.domain and spider1.ASIN. Take a look here to learn more about the difference between class and object variables: https://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/class-and-object-vars.html

Comment: @user45857, class attributes are accessible using the `self` object that is passed as first argument in class methods, e.g. `def start_request(self):
for i in self.ASIN:`